# Slow activeadmin index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activeadmin

I have Rails 5 with active admin gem working. In development I saw a lot of queries when run with `rail s`. Most of them are of type `CACHE(0.0ms)`.
Finally after some seconds it shows:

```
 Rendered /home/blabla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@test/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre4/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (10588.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10646ms (Views: 10338.2ms | ActiveRecord: 264.1ms)
```

Is the render view time the problem? In the index view I show a lot of information about some model an its associations. Also I add scoped_collection method with some includes for eager loading, but it is the same, It is tooo slow.... 
I appreciate any help...

Thank you!

Comment: I know its not the answer, but maybe you look into https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin . We switched from active_admin to rails_admin because with active_admin we got huge perfomance problems

Comment: Regarding ActiveAdmin: Try to figure out what SQL calls are in the logs and what took so long.... How many HTML are you generating btw?

Comment: It is more likely slow SQL than rendering.  Is it a large table? If so then `index pagination_total: false` may help.  If you are using AA scopes then scope counts can be an issue, not to be confused with scoped_collection with includes which definitely helps.

Comment: @SimonFranzen migrate to rails admin is not a possible solution because is a big system :(

Answer (score 3):

This is likely due to the filters. You can specify the filters you want to include, otherwise all attributes on the model will be added as a filter. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages.md.

Answer (score 2):

The `CACHE` ones are fine. This means that ActiveRecord already has the data and has not needed to do a DB call.

To diagnose the problem, I'd recommend the [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet), which will highlight slow queries caused by missing includes for you. To really drill down into performance, you could try the [rack mini-profiler gem](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) with the [flamegraph](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/03/19/flame-graphs-in-ruby-miniprofiler) extension. I've had success with these in diagnosing the issues causing the slownewss. Often it's an N+1 issue, but also the development version will recompile all the CSS every time you make an edit.

Speeding up ActiveAdmin by using `includes` is pretty simple:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    super.includes(:bill_address)
  end
end
```

Be aware that rendering in production will not include compiling assets on the fly, so this can be significant in development but not really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your models use The `has_many :through` association to set up a many-to-many connection, the number of records of the associated model is large, it's slow due to filters.

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

If the index of Patient is slow, it's better to add the below description.

```
preserve_default_filters!
remove_filter :physicians
```

https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html